# How to remove all bootstrap processing from radio button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am using coldfusion and bootstrap to make a site. I have some radio buttons that need to be selected depending on the value of a query output, but for some reason I cannot get any of the radio buttons to select at all based on their value. I was thinking maybe it is something in bootstrap 3 that is causing an issue.

Is there a way to remove all bootstrap style from a series of radio buttons?

Edit I am using this to check the boxes:

```
<cfinput type="radio" name="update_type" value="#form.update_type#" checked="#form.update_type eq 3#" />
```

Comment: css won't affect the code. Check console.

Comment: I think a more likely source of the problem is the ColdFusion code you are using to pre-select the radio buttons.

Comment: I am using this to select the checked status:

<cfinput type="radio" name="update_type" value="#form.update_type#" checked="#form.update_type eq 3#" />

Comment: try this <cfif isdefined('form.update_typ') and form.update_type eq 3>checked</cfif>

Comment: Thanks Leo. I tried what you suggested and got this error. The CFML compiler was processing:<ul><li>A cfinput tag beginning on line 865, column 50.<li>A cfinput tag beginning on line 865, column 50.</ul> The specific sequence of files included or processed is: D:\web\site1\dir4\index.cfm, line: 865 "

Comment: can you please add index.cfm code in question as seems you are missing tag.

Comment: Ahh I see. Well by changing the inputs to inputs instead of cfinput has allowed your method to work. They are now checking properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Different JS libraries do not always play well together. If you are already using an external library, do not use CF form fields (cfinput, etcetera). Stick with plain html form fields instead.

Answer (score 0):

Per Leo the Lion above:

```
<cfif isdefined('form.update_type') and form.update_type eq 3>checked</cfif>
```

Comment: If @LeoTheLion provided the solution, why not ask them to promote their comment to an answer as a thanks for helping ? :)

Comment: I'm new to this. There should be a way for me to mark the answer also.

Comment: Yes, S.O. works a bit differently than discussion forums. Takes a little getting used to... Often folks prefer to first use "comments" to suggest something they suspect will work, but are not 100% certain (to minimize the noise ratio).  If the asker confirms that suggestion turned out to be the solution, they usually ask the poster to promote their comment to an official "answer", which can then be marked as such to close out the thread.